# how to conditionally call an api depending on received value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, asynchronous, axios

i need to call an api depending on the value that im receiving on state,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([])

const firstAPI = async (val) => {
     return await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/rendition?name=${val}&&excel=true`)
        .then(res => console.log('excel', res))
   }

   const secondAPI = async (val) => {
      const limit = pageSize * (page - 1);
      return await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/rendition?id=${val}&&skip=${limit}&&take=${pageSize}&&excel=true`)
          .then((res) => {
             console.log('excelID', res);
         })
   }

   const handleExcelClick = (param) => {
      
      if(param.filter(item => typeof item === 'string')){
         firstAPI(param)
      } else {
         secondAPI(param)
      }
   }
   
   <Button onClick={() => handleExcelClick(selectedValue)} > Excel </Button>
```

so im receveing a value from 2 different inputs, which are stored in selectedValue state, which can  either be a string or a number, so i need to call an api depending on the value, if its a string, call the firstAPI, if it's a number, call the secondAPI. But whatever condition i put in, it ignores the if statement and just calls the first api which also triggers a 500 error because one of the apis only takes numbers as params, i don't know other way to approach this, any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Depends on data source of selectedValue of cause, but it seems that all data from inputs are a string. Maybe you need to check not typeof, but if the string presents a number?

Comment: you're correct, ts an array that either contains a string or a number as a string, how would you check if the param is a string number before it gets to the if statements? i also tried different ways to check the number but i couldn get it to work

Comment: does anybody have any idea? im a beginner and would appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it a lot of days ago, but i forgot to post my solution, so here it goes:

```
const handleExcelClick = (param: any) => {
if (typeof param === 'number') {
   return firstAPI(param);
} else if (param.some((i: any) => typeof i === 'string')) {
   return secondAPI(param);
}
```

};

i basically forgot to add a return to each statement, and there was also no point in filtering values based on just a filter method, so i used the "some" array method to just receive the values that return true if the condition is met, which is checking if the data type matches the statement

hope this helps anyone trying to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```js
...
if(param.filter(item => isNaN(item) )){
         firstAPI(param)
} else {
         secondAPI(param)
}
...
```

Comment: But pay attention that "param.filter(item => isNaN(item) )" returns new array! Maybe you need to check length of the new array to find out that you have at least one string parameter in param? Is really the selectedValue - array?

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help Oleg!